# How to pytest inside a container?

Tags: python, docker, unit-testing, containers, pytest

I have a script that is run inside a container.

I am planning to write some tests and run pytest on them.

So far so good. The problem is that I want to test the behavior of this script *inside the container*
It is no use to me to test this script under a separate virtual environment.

Now this container does not have pytest installed.

Before I have used poetry to have the tests environments ready but under the circumstances described, how do I set the pytest environment correctly to run these tests?

EDIT:

More details.

- I have a container with python 3.6.9 and pandas 0.22.0
  Pytest is not installed
- I created a virtual environment where I installed pytest. However I cannot use it since here pandas is not installed
- Well, then I have to install it right? I do install it and now pandas is 1.1.5
- Which defeats the purpose since I want to test the code under the same conditions

What can I do?

Comment: Do you want to execute the test in an automated way like devops or just run the tests in your windows laptop?

Comment: Both. First I plan to run it manually and then when I show them to my supervisors incorporate it to a pipeline. But that is second phase

Answer (score 0):

You can -
run container -> ensure it is running -> open bash/terminal inside the container -> install pytest -> run test cases. -> exit from container.

Open bash by the cmd -

`docker exec -it <container_name> bash`

It depends on how the docker image was built. check if you have the dockerfile. See if some virtual env is created or all packages are installed without env. If some virtual environment is present in container, search, activate and use it or else if all packages are installed without env, then simply install pytest and run test cases.

Comment: yes, I ve done that countless times. The thing is I run bash in the container and then what? install a virtual environment (where I install pytest or poetry) *inside* the container?

Comment: @KansaiRobot it depends on how the docker image was built. check if you have the dockerfile. See if some virtual env is created or all packages are installed without env. If some virtual environment is present in container, search, activate and use it or else if all packages are installed without env, then simply install pytest and run test cases

Comment: I have added more details about my particular problem. It is very important that I test the code under the same conditions of the container

Comment: @KansaiRobot do not create virtualenv since pandas is not in it. Its not compulsory to create virtualenv in a container. Install pytest directly inside container without env and run test cases.